# Booting Windows 8.1 on a cloned drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, clone

I had no way to backup my hard drive, so I had to clone it directly to my new drive. And because of the position of my GPU, I could only have the 2 hard drives plugged in, not the Blu-ray RE drive. So I had to clone the drive from within Windows 8.1. I know newer Windows create 2 partitions when installing from scratch, but the program I used (which was one recommended in a tutorial, can't remember its name but will add it when I do) could only clone one partition, and so I cloned the bigger partition. It used a "shadow copy". Of course it wouldn't boot. So I ran startup repair from my installation disk and it booted. But, my picture password was gone, all images were gone, I switched to password and entered my password. It showed "Preparing Windows" or something similar for a few minutes. Then it went to a black screen with pointer. No desktop or anything. Pressing CTRL + Del and choosing Task Manager also did nothing. Does anyone have any idea as to what to do to make it boot normally?

Comment: I recommend you try again, but this time use an emergency system on a USB flash drive. Something Linux-based that provides [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) should work, although I have no recommendations for specific emergency discs. Be sure to clone *all* your partitions -- at least two are required to boot, and the others may be extremely useful in some situations, so you don't want to omit them unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because the clone OS gave the OS volume a different letter than the original had.

What can happen:

- Plug drive into Computer Alpha. Alpha sees it as a new drive and gives it a drive letter associated with a drive ID. This is stored in the register.
- Clone boot disk of Alpha to new drive.
- Install cloned disk into Computer Beta. Beta boots using registry of Alpha, which has still assigned the not-C letter to the cloned drive.
- Computer tries and read off C, but it's assigned not-C.

KB article is: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249321
And instructions on changing the driver letter: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/223188?wa=wsignin1.0

- Let the computer sit on"Preparing Windows" for ~30minutes and it makes it to the blank blue desktop.
- ctrl + alt + del, run Task Manager.
- Click Show More, File->Run->cmd

Note what drive letter it shows. ie, E:\Windows\

You can't edit the registry on this machine because you can't use runas or UAC while it's in this state, and the keys we need to edit are admin only.

The way I edited the registry was by mounting the hive off the disk in another system.

- Start->Run
- Regedit run as admin (control+shift+enter to run as admin)
- Click hkey_local_machine
- Click File->Load Hive
- Select system hive: x:\windows\system32\config\system, X being the cloned drive.
- Enter "baddrive" as the name.
- Navigate to hkey_local_machine/baddrive/MountedDevices
- Locate the \DosDevices\E: (if E: was your drive)
- Delete all other \DosDevices\ entries. (AFTER selecting them and clicking File->Export to back them up)
- Right click \DosDevices\E:, "Rename", enter \DosDevices\C:
- File->Unload Hive
- Stick drive back into old computer and good luck!

I imagine you're able to get away without the task manager/cmd steps and deleting all the \DosDevices\ entries, but I did not test that. They're entries generated to be consistent between boots, so they're not very important.